# Invoking hub methods is slow over a local network

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr

I'm using the SignalR.client DLL to dialog with a website using SignalR.
It works perfectly when client and site are on the same machine. (Invoking hub method is immediate)

However, now that I set up the site on a machine over my network, calls (invokes) take 2.5 seconds average. (but work)

I ping the machine in <1ms.

Using Wireshark I saw that packets are sent after 2.5 seconds.

I debugged the SignalR.client dll and it's stuck at the System.Threading.Task level (called here, in HttpHelper.cs)

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes", Justification = "Exceptions are flowed back to the caller.")]
    public static Task<Stream> GetHttpRequestStreamAsync(this HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return TaskAsyncHelper.FromError<Stream>(ex);
        }
    }
```

Any idea of what could slow down the process?

Thanks a lot.

ps: I've used the SignalR chat example to reproduce the delay.

pps: Here's the (really simple) code of my test app:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://IP:PORT/SITENAME/");
    var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

    // Start the connection
    connection.Start().Wait();

    while (true)
    {
      string sMsg = string.Format("Hello world from winform! Sent(winform) at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
      Console.WriteLine("Sending data : " + sMsg);

      myHub.Invoke("Send", "Winform", sMsg).ContinueWith(task2 =>
      {
        if (task2.IsFaulted)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred during the method call {0}", task2.Exception.GetBaseException());
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Successfully called MethodOnServer at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
        }
      });
      Thread.Sleep(60*1000);
    }
```

Comment: Is it a single connection?

Comment: Yes, I create one connection. I update the main post with the code

Comment: Is it a console application? The code looks fine on the surface.

Comment: It's a windows form very simple (one button, on click => code I pasted)

Other than that, 
connection.Start().Wait(); takes 8.5seconds to perform with the remote config while it takes 0.25sec in localhost config

Comment: It's likely your connection limit, it's 2 by default in client apps (non ASP.NET). If you have any other uses of HttpWebRequest in your app it can affect this. Try increasing this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx  to a bigger number.

Comment: I would also use something like fiddler to look at the response, it might not be slow but it might be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to a bad local network configuration.
My professional computer was using an automatic configuration script + autodetect connection parameters which was slowing down everything. (=> stupid waste of time)

Thank you David for your answers & advice on using Fiddler (everything was working fine with it, because I found out Fiddler overrites proxy configuration)